# Elm : How to add a hidden input field in form without initial?

Tags: forms, elm

I meant how to input value for a field in model when submit form. A filed will  not display in form.

Comment: @Simon: 
for example: http://localhost:4000/#/action/id/token. 

I want to push id and token from url into form and then submit form. I also can't use initial form in this case, so i think i have to push id and token with hidden field

Answer (score 3):

Based on you additional information in the comment, I think you are going about things the wrong way. elm-simple-form is a library to help build and validate forms, it is rather less for the submitting of them. And in Elm you don't just build the UI and leave it to the standard html elements to do submitting.

To submit a form you will need to build the json object, or the multi-part form object, that you need and then send it directly using the `Http` library. It is while you are building your data to send that you can add in your additional information, such as a token. I do exactly this sort of thing, and have provided a library for use with Jwt tokens - http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/simonh1000/elm-jwt/2.0.0

Hope this helps